# Get path from openfile dialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, openfiledialog

I open a file in this way and that works fine:

```
var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog;

if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
    Browser.FileDoc = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Now, I want to get the path and pass it to another class. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? 'How to pass it to another class?': what class?

Comment: Stampy, your question is basically about **scope**, I would recommend you look on google for further reading about this topic

Comment: openFileDialog.FileName = path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the below menioned code.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
string filePath = ofd.FileName;
Class2 c=new Class2(filePath);
}
```

Suppose your another Class is Class2 then

```
public class Class2
{
string Path=String.Empty;
 public Class2(string _Path)
  {
    Path=_Path;
   }
}
```

Comment: I propose this : 

`public class Class2
{
 string _path=String.Empty;
 public Class2(string p)
 {
    Path=p;
 }


 public Path{get{return _path;}{set _path=value;}}
}`